# Removing blank space below header

Tags: customization

Does anyone know how to remove blank space below the header?

I am using the Wiral Lite Theme and the page with the blank space is www.akindvoice.org

Answer (score 2):

That header has `margin-bottom: 30px;`, so you have to add this to your CSS.

```
.site-header {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

If you want to remove it even more, the content has some margin-top, so you have to add this to your CSS.

```
.entry-content, {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

In case you don't know how to add CSS, [check this out](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/).